# How can I automate PeopleSoft using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, peoplesoft

I have a list of people and their emails in a spread sheet and I need to enter their emails into their account on People Soft V8. There is thousands of them so I was looking to automate this process.

I have started with the following code, but have been getting

run time error
Automation error 
Unspecified error

```
Sub GoToWebSiteUpdate()
Dim appIE As InternetExplorer
Dim sURL As String
Dim UserN As Variant
Dim myLoginID As String

Set appIE = New InternetExplorer
sURL = "Webaddress"
appIE.navigate sURL
appIE.Visible = True

     'Enter information in the first drop down
    Set UserN = appIE.document.getElementsById("InputBox")
    UserN(0).Value = "012354"


Set appIE = Nothing
End Sub
```

If anyone has any ideas that would be great, Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't PeopleSoft have some kind of email/data import system? I don't know why you would need VBA for this. You would just create your email data and import it in. http://peoplesoft.wikidot.com/data-mover-script-templates

Comment: It does have an import system, however, I just need to modify emails that are already in the system. Not just import table. Would this method support something like that or is there another way to do it? I just basically need to fill in a couple fields within a form and then click save

Comment: You need to import a table of corrected emails. I honestly have no idea how excel VBA would help you - assuming you already have a list of people's emails. You just need to get that data into PeopleSoft(by importing it).

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of pretty straightforward ways of doing this.

**1) The quick and dirty way:**
Use an Excel formula (in the last cell in each row) to concatenate together the values into a SQL statement (1 for each row). You can then run them in the SQL tool of your choice.

**2) The 'proper' method:**
Use ExcelToCI. This is an Excel upload tool which will run all the page validation etc. There's more to it than I can write here, but this is the link to the section on it in PeopleBooks:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28394_01/pt852pbh1/eng/psbooks/tcpi/book.htm?File=tcpi/htm/tcpi10.htm#H3002

kind regards

Duncan

Answer (score 0):

Actual working code i use to extract reports from peoplesoft. Code was prepared by looking up various blogs and code bases on the internet

The code will loop thru data ranges i.e. start dates and end dates and generate extracts. since the Psoft cant give more than 65K rows in extract i made this to run 7 days at a time.

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal HWND As Long) As Long

Sub PPS_Report_Extractor()

Dim Cell, Rng As Range   'Declaring cell for looping thru date range
'Dim appIE As Object      'InternetExplorer.Application
Dim appIE As InternetExplorer
Dim sURL As String       'URL String
Dim Element As Object    'HTMLButtonElement
Dim btnInput As Object   'MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
Dim ElementCol As Object 'MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim Link As Object       'MSHTML.HTMLAnchorElement
Dim Counter, myNum       'Add Counter
    Counter = 0          'Declare Start for Counter
    myNum = 147          'Declare the number of repitition required

RemNamedRanges 'Delete the older ranges

'---Set New Range of reporting start dates -----
Range("A1").Offset(1, 0).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Name = "ElementCol"

Set Rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Elementcol")

'---Launch the IE -----
' Set appIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Set appIE = New InternetExplorerMedium


sURL = "" ' open the URL by loggin intot PPS query then past that url here

appIE.Navigate sURL
appIE.Visible = True

'While appIE.Busy
'    DoEvents
'Wend

Pause (5) 'Allow IE to load

SendKeys "{ENTER}" 'Hit log on button in IE

'-Loop to generate the Files for full year starts here ---

For Each Cell In Rng

A = Format(Cell.Value, "DD-MM-YYYY")
B = Format(Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value, "DD-MM-YYYY")
'----Code for extraction ---START---

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:5")
'Pause (5) 'Allow IE to load

appIE.Document.getelementbyid("InputKeys_bind2").Value = A
appIE.Document.getelementbyid("InputKeys_bind3").Value = B
appIE.Document.getelementbyid("#ICQryDownloadExcelFrmPrompt").Click

Pause (5)
SendKeys "{ENTER}", 5

'---Wait for excel generation to complete

I = 0
Set fo = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Do Until fo.FileExists(OutFile) 'Loop until the output file is created, this could be infinity if there is a problem
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:2")) 'Holds the program for 2 seconds
    DoEvents
    I = I + 1
    If (I = 10) Then
    SendKeys "%S" 'Alt S to save the report
    GoTo 1
    End If
Loop
1
'----Code for extraction ---END---
Next Cell

'-Loop to generate the Files for full year Ends here here ---

MsgBox "The range has " & K & " rows."


End Sub
```